# Home firewall with application monitoring

Tags: firewall, monitoring

I'm looking for a way of monitoring http at application level at home. As such I don't want anything hugely complex or expensive - just a way of looking at, say, Facebook usage by device.

Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this? Would prefer an appliance, as I don't want to be running stuff on my home PC all the time to monitor it.

Considered Meraki, but may be overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, look at the [OpenWrt](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/start) docs and see if it can do enough of what you need. If so, that is likely the cheapest/easiest solution.

Otherwise you may need a commercial-grade firewall appliance such as a SonicWall or a serious open source firewall such as [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) running on dedicated hardware. And even those might not give you exactly what you want.

Some routers/firewalls will provide generic reports of say the top 10 most visited web addresses but they won't necessarily log usage by user--just aggregated total traffic through the firewall. And some allow you to set up specific logging for specific users but that might give you too much data--as in each individual access.

You can also use a lan "sniffer" like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor all network traffic but that's a fairly steep learning curve and would require a PC be running it 24/7.

And, regardless, I'm not aware of any low-cost solutions that will track *time* spent on sites--they only will track data bandwidth/packets/etc. So someone could spend hours on Facebook mostly reading text on Tuesday and only 10 minutes on Wednesday but spend it all watching videos. From the firewall's perspective, it would show higher Facebook usage on Wednesday. If you want to track usage by time your best option is to install monitoring software on each PC.